# Distance to features in R raster with buffer

Tags: raster, r, distance

Is there a method to calculate the distance to features in a raster, but only within some buffer distance?

At the moment I'm just using `distance(rast)`, and then setting all the values greater than the buffer  to be equal to the buffer: `rast[rast > buffer] = buffer`

Here's an example:

```
 r <- raster(xmn=1035792, xmx= 1116792, ymn=825303.6, ymx=937803.6, resolution = 12.5,crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=42.122774 +lat_2=49.01518 +lat_0=45.568977 +lon_0=-84.455955 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")
r <- setValues(r, 0)
x <- c(1088419, 1093067, 1090190, 1087977, 1088419)
y <- c(895030.8, 894366.9, 892153.9, 893703.0, 895030.8)
poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(data.frame(x,y))), ID = 1)))
r <- mask(r, poly)   
rD <- distance(r) 
rD[rD > buff] = buff
```

This is just a small, very simple example, but some of the rasters I'm using are extremely large, and can be much more complicated than just this little polygon (for example road networks over whole countries), and the distance function can be extremely slow when this is the case. So, I'm wondering if there's a better method, that will only calculate the distance up to a maximum buffer and hopefully save on computation time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the locations of non-NA raster cells with `as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)` - that gives all the cells of your feature. Convert those to spatial points and then buffer them to get a polygonal buffer. You could then mask the full grid of points with that buffer and compute distances for only those points.

Use the `sf` package for your spatial data and hence `st_buffer` for your buffering. You may have to convert back to `sp` objects for `raster` package interoperability.